# Memory error while compiling

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, contract-debugging

Please have a look at the contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;

/**
* @title SafeMath
* @dev Math operations with safety checks that throw on error
 */
 library SafeMath {
 function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    if (a == 0) {
    return 0;
   }
   uint256 c = a * b;
   assert(c / a == b);
   return c;
  }

  function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
   // assert(b > 0); // Solidity automatically throws when dividing by 0
   uint256 c = a / b;
   // assert(a == b * c + a % b); // There is no case in which this doesn't hold
   return c;
  }

  function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
   assert(b <= a);
   return a - b;
 }

 function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
   uint256 c = a + b;
   assert(c >= a);
   return c;
  }
 }

contract Token {
 /// @return total amount of tokens
  function totalSupply() public pure returns (uint256 supply);

  /// @param _owner The address from which the balance will be retrieved
 /// @return The balance
 function balanceOf(address _owner) public pure returns (uint256 balance);

 /// @notice send `_value` token to `_to` from `msg.sender`
/// @param _to The address of the recipient
 /// @param _value The amount of token to be transferred
 /// @return Whether the transfer was successful or not
 function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success);

  /// @notice send `_value` token to `_to` from `_from` on the condition it is approved by `_from`
 /// @param _from The address of the sender
 /// @param _to The address of the recipient
 /// @param _value The amount of token to be transferred
 /// @return Whether the transfer was successful or not
  function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public 
  returns (bool success);

 /// @notice `msg.sender` approves `_addr` to spend `_value` tokens
 /// @param _spender The address of the account able to transfer the tokens
 /// @param _value The amount of wei to be approved for transfer
  /// @return Whether the approval was successful or not
  function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success);

  /// @param _owner The address of the account owning tokens
 /// @param _spender The address of the account able to transfer the tokens
 /// @return Amount of remaining tokens allowed to spent
 function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public pure returns (uint256 remaining);

 event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);
  event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);

  uint public decimals;
 string public name;
  }

 /**
 * @title Ownable
 * @dev The Ownable contract has an owner address, and provides basic 
authorization control
* functions, this simplifies the implementation of "user permissions".
 */
  contract Ownable {

  address public owner;

  /**
   * @dev The Ownable constructor sets the original `owner` of the contract to the sender
  * account.
   */
  constructor() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Throws if called by any account other than the owner.
   */
  modifier onlyOwner() {
   require(msg.sender == owner);
    _;
   }

   /**
    * @dev Allows the current owner to transfer control of the contract to a newOwner.
   * @param newOwner The address to transfer ownership to.
   */
  function transferOwnership(address newOwner) onlyOwner public {
    require(newOwner != address(0));      
   owner = newOwner;
  }

 }
 contract Gateway is Ownable{
using SafeMath for uint;


struct BuyInfo {
  address buyerAddress; 
  address sellerAddress;
  uint value;
  address currency;
}

mapping(address => mapping(uint => BuyInfo)) public payment;


function getBuyerAddressPayment(address _sellerAddress, uint _orderId) public pure returns(address){
  return  payment[_sellerAddress][_orderId].buyerAddress;
}    
function getSellerAddressPayment(address _sellerAddress, uint _orderId) public pure returns(address){
  return  payment[_sellerAddress][_orderId].sellerAddress;
}    

function getValuePayment(address _sellerAddress, uint _orderId) public pure returns(uint){
  return  payment[_sellerAddress][_orderId].value;
}    

function getCurrencyPayment(address _sellerAddress, uint _orderId) public pure returns(address){
  return  payment[_sellerAddress][_orderId].currency;
}


function payToken(address _tokenAddress, address _sellerAddress, uint _orderId,  uint _value) public returns (bool success){
  require(_tokenAddress != address(0));
  require(_sellerAddress != address(0)); 
  require(_value > 0);
  Token token = Token(_tokenAddress);
  require(token.allowance(msg.sender, this) >= _value);
  payment[_sellerAddress][_orderId] = BuyInfo(msg.sender, _sellerAddress, _value, _tokenAddress);
  success = true;
}
function payEth(address _sellerAddress, uint _orderId, uint _value) internal returns  (bool success){
  require(_sellerAddress != address(0)); 
  require(_value > 0);
  payment[_sellerAddress][_orderId] = BuyInfo(msg.sender, _sellerAddress, _value, 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001);    
  success = true;
}

function balanceOfToken(address _tokenAddress, address _Address) public pure returns (uint) {
  Token token = Token(_tokenAddress);
  return token.balanceOf(_Address);
}

function bytesToAddress(bytes source) internal pure returns(address) {
  uint result;
  uint mul = 1;
  for(uint i = 20; i > 0; i--) {
    result += uint8(source[i-1])*mul;
    mul = mul*256;
  }
  return address(result);
}
function() external payable {
  require(msg.data.length == 20); 
  require(msg.value > 99999999999);
  address sellerAddress = bytesToAddress(bytes(msg.data));
  uint value = msg.value.div(10000000000).mul(10000000000);
  uint orderId = msg.value.sub(value);
  payEth(sellerAddress, orderId, value);
  }
}
```

Actually the main contract is working fine can be found in Etherscan. [Main Contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x3E0371bcb61283c036A48274AbDe0Ab3DA107a50#code)

**What am I trying to do?**
As you can that there is a charge that can be deducted in the [main contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x3E0371bcb61283c036A48274AbDe0Ab3DA107a50#code). I'm trying to create a new contract without that function.

**What is the error in the mentioned code?**
The error is in line **161**.
**Error -** TypeError: Data location must be "storage" or "memory" for parameter in function, but none was given.
    function bytesToAddress(bytes source) internal pure returns(address) {
                            ^----------^

I'm trying to new and trying to modify the contract. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the keyword `memory`, so it becomes: `function bytesToAddress(bytes memory source) internal pure returns(address) {`. Otherwise the compiler doesn't know where to (temporarily?) store the variable contents.

You can read more about these here: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html#storage-memory-and-the-stack